# How to publish html report inside VSTS

Tags: html, report, azure-devops, unzip

I have a simple batch (let's call it `run_job.bat`) job that I set up in VSTS as *release definition*. VSTS reads this file from the remote git repository that is also set up in VSTS.

The agent is configured on a remote machine to access certain folder, say `C:\AllScans\FolderWhereScanIsRunning\` bring the necessary batch file in there and start the run. The job runs some scan against web application and generates report file with some unknown for me extension.

Another job then runs as queue in VSTS (let's call it `run_report.bat`) that transforms this unckown file to zip file where `.html`, `.css` and `.js` files are sitting. Simply exporting this manually to another folder and double clicking on the `index.html` file shows nicely looking html report on how the scan is run, and if there were any failures during it.

My question: is it possible to access this zip file `C:\AllScans\FolderWhereScanIsRunning\report.zip`, unzip it and bring this `index.html` file within the VSTS UI? I want be able for my other coworkers to see the results of the scan in html format without leaving VSTS interface? Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not directly publish your html report in your build summary? Could this meet your requirement?

Comment: The problem that I don't use build, rather release definition

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: How about put your  `index.html` file in a custom VSTS extension? Take a look at this  [Develop a web extension for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/get-started/node?view=vsts), this extension just html page which definitely compatible with your report. You just need to unzip the file and extract the content.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT thanks for the answer, but it's a pity: I'm not the owner of the VSTS account and I don't think I can install custom developed extensions

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to achieve this by default.

A workaround would be deploy the html files to a web page which allow iframe embedding and then use "Embedded Webpage" widget in VSTS to show the content.