# Publish HTML test report in VSTS release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have BBDfy html test report which needs to be published in VSTS CD pipeline. When  I run integration tests in VS2017 IDE I can see the report under below path. These are using `XUnit` and `BDDfy`

path : `C:\Repo\SiteSearch-Framework\src\XXX.SiteSearch.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests\bin\Debug\BDDfy.html`.

Currently I am able to run these integration tests as part of release pipeline and wanted to publish this `BDDfy.html` report as well.

[image]

After implementing above task I can see this error : `##[warning]Failed to read D:\a\r1\a\SiteSearchFramework\e2e\bin\Release\BDDfy.html. Error : '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 88, position 154..`

By looking at the below [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142616/how-to-publish-html-report-inside-vsts) looks like no option  other than the web extension. Still the same case or is there a solution?